# Prevent Multiple jQuery Menus From Being Triggered

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm new to jQuery, and am having an issue with implementing multiple instances of a menu on page. The issue is simple enough: click one menu and they all open. I've gleaned from other posts that I have to traverse the DOM (I think?) and attach either attach a class to each menu or something similar.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".submenu").hover(
function(){
    $(".sub").slideToggle(250);
},
function(){
    $(".sub").hide();
}
```

);
});

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wmFn9/2/ (ignore the layout for now, just a quick copy paste)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$(".sub")` to `$(".sub", this)`. Period.

Comment: Thank you! Ya, it was that simple. *d'oh*